# Vaadin 7.6.7 - Navigator does not working

Tags: vaadin, navigator

In 7.6.6, it worked fine!

From version 7.6.7, navigator enter function is called once only within page display. So navigation within the page can not make sense. Vaadin may change the "enter" function call mechanism.

I want to use navigator for keeping the status change within the page. 
How can i make navigator change effect to the page without enter function?

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing for me. It sounds like you'd want navigation _within_ one of your views. Also I've ran a quick test with a couple of simple views and it seems to be working as expected as you can see [here](http://imgur.com/BFOBucc). Can you share a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) or at least some code?

Comment: I want to use BROWSER Back and Foreward button. But 'enter' is not fired on back/foreward event. It fired only once at View's full display. Untiil version 7.6.6, enter fied well within page navigation with URI fragment. The Morfic's example does not use browser function. ... Difficult English! Sorry.

Comment: Check [link](https://vaadin.com/download/release/7.6/7.6.7/release-notes.html)

Comment: **At V7.6.8, the problem is solved.** Vaddin may do a wrong patch  at v7.6.7!

Comment: Although it sounds a tad different, it might've been related to [this ticket](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/20029) from the [RN list](https://vaadin.com/download/release/7.6/7.6.8/release-notes.html)

Comment: Dear Morfic. It's right. Vaddin restored the behaviour of View's enter.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. Use UriFragmentChangedListener.

1. Enroll URI fragment listener

   Page.getCurrent().addUriFragmentChangedListener(new UriFragmentChangedListener() {

   ```
       @Override
       public void uriFragmentChanged(UriFragmentChangedEvent event) {
           String frag = event.getUriFragment();
           if (frag.contains("query"))
               enterForFragment(event.getUriFragment());
       }
   });
   ```
2. fire fragment listener

   Page.getCurrent().setUriFragment(navTo);

PS.
'**enterForFragment**' fuction do same task of '**enter**'

Comment: It do well for single View. But it do not work with multiple view.

Comment: In multi view, setUriFragment force to change to start view! I can not find the reason!